# HTML Image won't fit in blank space

Tags: html, css

I am having issues with an image not fitting in my container. Btw the th:each will just do another div class = "profile-picture". Also I noticed that uncommenting float:left will make the image fit and less spaces between the images, but I would like not to use it unless it is the only way.I am not an expert at web designing, but I though this would work as the container width is 1200px, profile picture div is 390px and margin is 5px, so 400px in total. 400px x 3 = 1200px, so it should the 1st of the 2nd row should be in the 1st row, right?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="profile-picture"
         th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, user.pictures.size() - 1)}">
        <img th:src="@{'/user/' + ${user.id} + '/image/' + ${i}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*profile*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    overflow: auto;
}

.profile-picture {
    margin: 5px;
    /*border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
    /*float: left;*/
    width: 390px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.profile-picture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 267px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you place inline-block elements next to each other the browser will assume you will want a little blank space between the elements. This is the normal behaviour of inline elements. If you float them the elements will not follow this normal behaviour since you get them out of the normal flow.